# How to test DeepLabV3+ on on test set?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, deeplab

The model zoo provided few pre-trained models with several datasets such like PASCAL VOC2012, Cityscapes, ...etc. I am trying to run it on my local and it works as well with validation set because of they are providing the code to convert train/validation set to tfrecord. However, I couldn't test DeepLabV3+ with test set.

Is there any way to run with test set?

Answer (score 0):

Use [inference] and loop over all images.[1](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/deeplab_demo.ipynb)